# How might a Keras model be exported to a mathematical expression?

Tags: keras

What would be a way to export a trained Keras model (in this case an Inception CNN) to a mathematical expression, such as one suitable for inclusion in a LaTeX document?

I see an attempt here but it is faultering: https://gist.github.com/umachkaalex/09e948a2c01c9cf29de6156f8b7d37da#file-approximation_2-ipynb (source article: https://alasko.medium.com/convert-simple-neuron-network-to-mathematician-notation-58a0d72f0337)